# Where do I put <script src=...></script> in an angular-fullstack-generator project?

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack, mobile-angular-ui

This should be straight forward, but I'm stuck.

I'm trying to include [mobile-angular-ui](http://mobileangularui.com/docs/) in an [angular-fullstack-generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) project but I keep getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  mobile-angular-ui.min.js:1
```

I'm adding the following at the end of the body of the _index.html, and the network tab is returning the proper 200 response.

```
<script src="/node_modules/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If I use import in app.js like this

```
import mobileUi from '../../node_modules/mobile-angular-ui/dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.js';
```

Then I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined   mobile-angular-ui.js:2584
```

Where am I going wrong, where am I supposed to include this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, with the angular-fullstack app from https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack,
you just have to write:

```
npm install --save mobile-angular-ui angular angular-route
```

And all the dependencies will automatically be built.

Comment: Thanks for answering Wandrille, that command is downloading the packages, but when I try to inject/import it, either I include it in the html (and get the Token error) or I import it in app.js and get the documentElement error.

Once I run the npm install, I'm stuck...

Comment: So, i have installed a new project. I have also done npm install mobile-angular-ui. And i got the same error as you. I have no clue why, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In angular-fullstack, all front end libraries are handled/installed through bower and all back end libraries are handled through npm.

So if you want to use mobile-angular-ui, which is a front end library, you should try installing it like this.

```
bower install --save mobile-angular-ui angular angular-route
```

Then add the module dependency

> mobile-angular-ui

in app.js of client side Then serve the project again. Now your dependency will be added automatically in your index.html file and you won't need to automatically include it in your index.html